# What does the "4G" that appears on my iPhone 4S's AT&T network indicator mean?

Tags: ios, cellular-carriers, 4g

Since upgrading my iPhone 4S to iOS 5.1 (from 5.0.1), the AT&T network status indicator now reads "4G" where it once read "3G". What has changed from the previous version? Does this "4G" mean the same thing as it does on the "new iPad"?

Comment: Basically everything to do with cell networks is a mess, and the indicators on the status bar are an indication of speed, ie if it says 4G things will download faster than if it says 3G.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Nomenclature

The terms **2G**, **3G** and **4G** do not refer to a *specific* wireless standard, but a a whole *bunch* of different standards:

[image]

There has been controversy on what standards should be referred to as **4G**. When Apple introduced the iPhone 4S, they followed other companies in referring to HSDPA as a **4G** standard. HSPA+ is the successor to HSDPA.

[image]

## DC-HSPA+

Technically, **HSDPA** and **HSPA+** are **3G** wireless standards. However, HSPA+ has received technological upgrades which increased the theoretical throughput to become similar to that of **LTE**.

**If 4G were to indicate speed rather than a wireless standard, it's legitimate to refer to the upgraded HSPA+ as 4G**. However, this improved HSPA+ should be referred to as **DC-HSPA+**, not merely HSPA+.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It means that you are connected on HSPA+. It's actually a 3G technology, and unfortunately, you probably won't experience any speed increase in downloading or surfing.

The 4G technology for the "new iPad" is LTE, and is much faster than the existing 3G band.

[4G iPhone On AT&T? New Network Indicator Causes Controversy](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/03/08/4g-iphone-att_n_1333431.html)

Answer (score 2):

The 5.1 update provides a labeling change for iPhone 4S users - "3G" is now "4G". As the other answerers have noted, HSPA+ is technically considered a 4G technology. A [MacWorld article](http://www.macworld.com/article/165768/2012/03/ios_5_1_update_brings_4g_label_to_iphone_4s_on_atandts_network.html) states:

> The **4G label** in iOS 5.1 instead reflects AT&T’s perspective, namely
>   that **the carrier’s HSPA+ network (also known as Evolved High-Speed
>   Packet Access) qualifies as 4G technology**. Carriers tend to refer to both HSPA+ and LTE—the cellular network technology built into the new iPad—as 4G, though the inner workings of the technologies are vastly different.

The new iPad, however, uses LTE, a different 4G technology. There's more information about the differences between LTE and 3G in [this MacWorld article](http://www.macworld.com/article/165762/2012/03/what_lte_means_for_apples_new_ipad.html#lsrc.mod_rel).